# I need help reading this code to understand what it is doing so I can convert it to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to learn JavaScript. I know jQuery is a library to JavaScript but the syntax is so different and I just need some help reading what the code is doing so that I can recreate it using JavaScript.

I am working on a project from a youtube tutorial that adds items to a WebSQL database usig jQuery Mobile I am at a point in the tutorial where we are updating an item we entered. The code is able to populate the update form with the information we entered.  The code works perfectly but it's in jQuery and I wanted to change it to JavaScript if possible. Can you help me by explaining what the code is actually doing and how to convert it to JavaScript?

HTML code of the update form

`````
       <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Update Product</h1>
       </div>
       <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
           <form>
               <div class="ui-field-contain">
                   <label for="newName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Name</label>
                   <input type="text" id="newName" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="New Name"/><br/>
                   <label for="newQuantity" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Quantity</label>
                   <input type="number" name="number" pattern="[0-9}" id="newQuantity" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="New Quantity"/><br/>
                   <button class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left"
                           id="btnupdate" onclick="updateProduct()">Update</button>
               </div>
           </form>

       </div>
````    </div>

JavaScript Code of populating the form and then updating the changes.

````var currentProduct = {
  id:-1,
  name: "",
  quantity:-1,
````}

````$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#updatedialog', function() {
 $('#newName').val(currentProduct.name);
 $('#newQuantity').val(currentProduct.quantity);
});

function updateProduct() {
 var newName = $('#newName').val();
 var newQuantity = $('#newQuantity').val();
 productHandler.updateProduct(currentProduct.id, newName, newQuantity);
}
`````

```
    databaseHandler.db.transaction(
        function(tx){
            tx.executeSql(
            "Update product set name=?, quantity=? where id=?",
             [newName, newQuantity, _id],
              function(tx, results){},
               function(tx, error){//todo: display this message to user
                    console.log("Error updating product" + error.message);
                 }
               );
        }
    );
}
```

I would like to populate the update form with the product info, change any info on the form and update the information using JavaScript not jQuery.

Comment: Yes I understand that which is why  I stated "I know jQuery is a library to JavaScript" I am asking about the entire code, I want to know what the code is doing so I can understand how to change the jQuery to JS

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to change JQuery code to Javascript I use this webpage: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ and [Jquery to Javascript](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/wiki/Converting-jQuery-to-JavaScript). You should have all the information you need there to change the Jquery parts to javascript.

The most obvious is replacing the "$" with document.querySelectorAll.

Example:

```
$('#newName').val(currentProduct.name);
```

Replace by:

```
document.getElementById('newName').value = currentProduct.name;
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I saw that website yesterday I need to go check it out in detail. Thanks that does help!

Comment: I have testing out the document.querySelectorAll method but the form is not populated with the information do you know why it would work perfectly with jQuery but not with JavaScript?

Comment: @ElianaHebrew Yes I made a mistake in my javascript. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery parts:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#updatedialog', function() {
    $('#newName').val(currentProduct.name);
    $('#newQuantity').val(currentProduct.quantity);
});

function updateProduct() {
    var newName = $('#newName').val();
    var newQuantity = $('#newQuantity').val();
    productHandler.updateProduct(currentProduct.id, newName, newQuantity);
}
```

And here's how you'd convert them to pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("updatedialog").addEventListener("pagebeforeshow", function() {
    document.getElementById("newName").value = currentProduct.name;
    document.getElementById("newQuantity").value = currentProduct.name;
});

function updateProduct() {
    var newName = document.getElementById("newName").value
    var newQuantity = document.getElementById("newQuantity").value
    productHandler.updateProduct(currentProduct.id, newName, newQuantity);
}
```

Comment: Oh okay so the $ in jQuery  is the document.getElementById in JavaScript?

Comment: So I testing this out and using Javascript instead of jQuery takes away the product information that is populated. For JavaScript do I need another line of code to make that happen?

Comment: So the JavaScript code shouldn't stop the form from populating with the product info?